# Implementing sieve of eratosthenes in bitwise form

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to learn the concept behind using bitwise for the sieve of Eratosthenes. From what I read I understand that each element of the prime array stores the prime status ( prime -> 0 or composite ->1) of 64 numbers. So just 1 element is enough for 64 numbers. What I don't understand is how that number is mapped to that bit and what is the logic behind it?

In the following statement:
(prime[x/64] & (1 << ((x >> 1) & 31)))

if x is 5 then 5 >> 1 = 2 (5/2=2) and after modulo 32 we get 2. Does this mean the 2nd bit (out of 64 bits) corresponds to the number 5? will the 2nd bit hold the prime status of number 5?

I want to understand on what basis we come up with 2 (why we shift right by 2 bits and then modulo 32) and what's the logic behind it. Also I ran the program and tried to debug to better understand it and found that the element in prime array goes negative at some point. Prime array is of data type int so each element in it is of type int (32 bits). How can an int (32 bit) store prime status of 64 numbers ( 64 numbers require 64 bits to store status I am guessing)

It would be helpful if someone could help me! I looked at other similar questions on stack overflow but still couldnt understand thats why I am posting again. Please let me know how I can make the question better since I am new to stack overflow.

```
 
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

 
bool ifnotPrime(int prime[], int x) 
{ 
    
    return (prime[x/64] & (1 << ((x >> 1) & 31))); 
} 

bool makeComposite(int prime[], int x) 
{ 
    
    prime[x/64] |= (1 << ((x >> 1) & 31)); 
} 


void bitWiseSieve(int n) 
{ 
    
    int prime[n/64]; 

    memset(prime, 0, sizeof(prime)); 

     
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) { 

        
        if (!ifnotPrime(prime, i)) 
            for (int j = i * i, k = i << 1; j < n; j += k) 
                makeComposite(prime, j); 
    } 

    
    printf("2 "); 

    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2) 
        if (!ifnotPrime(prime, i)) 
            printf("%d ", i); 
} 


int main() 
{ 
    int n = 30; 
    bitWiseSieve(n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I think it's only storing odd numbers, hence 32 odd numbers in 32 bits covers a range of 64 numbers odd and even. You already have an exception for printing 2, and then your printing loop only loops over odd numbers.

Comment: hi @Rup I am understanding more now thanks to your answer. Is this related to shifting right by 2 and modulo 32 ? I am still confused about that